# Custom Asp.net Navigation Menu

Tags: c#, asp.net

Are there any recommended ways on developing a custom navigation menu in ASP.Net similar to how the built-in Asp.Menu navigation/web.sitemap works?

We need to replicate the exact menu structure that a DNN site has for another custom built web application, and its ability to be generated on the fly in case of any addition to the parent menu (which can be done dynamically with DNN).

The nav hierarchy structure can be found in the DNN database, but I am not sure how to approach custom building the menu; or even if it can be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a custom sitemap provider. There's a decent [article on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/cc163657.aspx) that should point you in the right direction.

Then, if you want to customise the rendering of the sitemap, I've found this [4guys article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210519001538/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030806-1.aspx) to be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if we're talking about webforms or **mvc**, but for mvc the https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider is an **excellent** choise. you can easily change what and how get's rendered.